# Is there a stackoverflow site for vim?

Tags: search, vim, highlighting

It appears that vim.org supports questions only via mail and/or mail digests, and vim's own internal :help utility doesn't give me what I think I need regarding highlighting, so I'm here to ask my question. General searching via google gives me no good hits, possibly revealing that I'm just not asking with the right search terms.

My question will be: Can I highlight by regex independent of search highlighting?

If there is a stackoverflow site intended for vim questions such as that?

Comment: There's no specific Stack Exchange site for Vim, and Vim questions are generally considered to be on topic here at Stack Overflow, so you're in the right place.

Comment: You're very welcome here (but try to compose a more detailed question next time), as long as there's a relation to software development. For install and UI issues, the parallel SuperUser site is more suited, and there are also OS-specific Vim questions on the Unix / Ubuntu and MacOS sister sites.

Comment: Meta discussion about where to ask questions is off-topic, which is why I have voted to close this question. But asking about Vim's search highlighting is probably fine; in that case you should change your question title.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest built-in way is

```
:mat[ch] {group} /{pattern}/
```

e.g. `:match ErrorMsg /ERROR:/`; you have two more slots with `:2match` and `:3match` (some plugins use those, too), and programatically an arbitrary number via the `matchadd()` function.

#### Differences

Whereas the search pattern is global in scope, the `:match` applies only to *the current window*. That can be unexpected. If you would like to have a quick way to define (and also jump to) some additional patterns (and don't mind installing a plugin), I can recommend you my [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666).

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of vim questions here on SO answered by some highly skilled vimmers so I don't see the need for a separate vim-SO-site...

But if you feel like creating one, you can always propose one at http://area51.stackexchange.com/

To answer your vim question: Have a look at this page http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words

Which describes a method to use multiple highlights.